# Status of review queues

Tags: discussion

In recent weeks the processing of reviewing queues has declined. Right now the situation is particularly dire, with almost 150 first posts awaiting review. How do we address this situation?

One stop-gap measure is removing daily review limits, which could help determined users to quickly clear the queue in such circumstances. A more long-term measure is to renew the community's commitment to help with site moderation, for example by publicizing the issue on meta.

Comment: I think publicizing the issue on meta is a good first step!

Comment: One of the reasons I find it hard to do reviewing is that I don't exactly know what I should edit and not.  Should we fix grammar?  Should we make formulas into LaTeX?  Should we rephrase questions to make them easier to understand?  Where do we stop?

Comment: @PålGD, it's up to you.  My impression is that the purpose of first-post review is to help folks who are here to guide them on how to be successful on this site.  So, you could make improvements yourself; or you could offer suggestions to them about how they could improve their own post.

Comment: Maybe we could write down something (here?) that sets out the "rules" of what moderators can and should do with a post?  I'm often afraid I'm taking it too far with my edits...

Comment: A related question: do we have three active moderators?

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue Yuval. I go through the queue every now and then, but I usually have only looked at close votes for no particular reason. Maybe we should do a coordinated effort to go through the queues?

Comment: It seems to be happening on its own.

Comment: I'll try to do a little more in the coming days as well.

Comment: It's down to zero!

Comment: I am pretty new to review first posts, but here's my opinion on the topic: when I try go to the review queue, I often see first posts that are already edited/commented so I don't quite see the point to do something. When browsing newly active questions, I already edit/comment them if necessary without doing so via the review queue. Why not automatically remove a post from the review queue if it is already edited/commented by someone above a certain threshold of reputation? (dunno if that's easy to do, though)

Answer (score 1):

> "How do we address this situation?"

I recently asked a similar question here: [How can we get users to participate more in Meta?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3254/4506)

Unfortunatlely only one person answered, and their answer was something most of us already know, which is that we can make Meta questions [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

I also took a bit more of an "aggressive" stance here: [We need more people actively using the edit queue](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1757/61663) where I actively request for the community to be more active in review queues. Perhaps you could add the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to it so that people that are not familiar with the reviewing system, can have attention drawn to it!