# We need more people actively using the edit queue

Tags: discussion

How is it that this Hot Network Question with 1000 views has survived so long with this typo in the title?

[image]

I tried fixing it but can't make an edit until the edit queue on the question is cleared. A moderator (D.W.) has also [pointed out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57763681#57763681) that this has been an issue for a while.

Can we please have more people keeping an eye on the review queues? I've never seen such long wait times for ***crucial edits*** like this one, on an SE site before!

Comment: I'm still confused why should I care about review queries. I mean, when I look at "Top Questions" page, when I find a question I may care about, I'm doing the same thing as during review queries: upvote/downvote, comment, suggest edits, answer, flag, ignore, etc. So essentially, review query sounds like a way to attract my attention to questions/answers I don't care about, and, well, I don't care what happens with them. Moreover, it seems that the chance of encountering crap in review queries is much higher, and I believe that the crap I see already is more than enough.

Comment: Dmitry: **I respect your right to choose not to help with the moderation.** Hopefully some others care enough to keep the site in good order.

Comment: I would like to highlight few points: 1) What's wrong with keeping the part of the site I care about in good order? If everyone would do this, then the only uncovered parts would be the ones no one cares about. 2) There are more efficients ways to keep the site in good order (of course, moderation is required, but it should be the last resort, not the main solution). Why there are crappy questions? Because posting a question is as simple as typing and and posting. People are not even forced to look at the tour (you can check how many new users looked at the page) ...

Comment: ... and the guidance which is provided there is not nearly enough: we know a lot of common issues - why are they not listed there? There is also an acceptance from the community side: people are OK with homeworks without any efforts and with answers helping these people to cheat; even obviously bad (at least from my point of view) posts with a lot of views don't get nearly as much downvotes as they deserve, and keep appearing at the top page. We can also have some red-flag tags (e.g. for flag `python` there should be a very noticeable warning that the question is not for this site).

Comment: My point is: the problems are more severe than "a lack of people which want to take care of the mess", and adding more external moderation only fixes the symptoms. And when taking care of individual cases in review queues, I don't feel any sense of accomplishment: I only feel frustration from the fact that no matter how much I edit, the source of the problem is still there. I also would like to admit that the situation here is much better than on math.se and [SO].

Comment: @Dmitry I agree with a lot of the points you're making, but we have to work with the system we have in place: the Stack Exchange company is not going to be giving a warning to users that use the python tag, and is not going to force people to look at the tour. You've made it clear that you're not happy with the low-quality content, and that's exactly the type of content you could be helping fix/remove from the review queues, but **I totally respect your choice not to look at the review queues.** We need others to do it though.

Answer (score 4):

I just went through the queue. There were *three* posts in there. That doesn't seem to be a lot; but I don't usually check the queue, so I don't know what's normal.

That said, it's true that we don't have all too many users with enough reputation to access the queues. I'm not sure whether appealing to users who enjoy answering over editing, or have already disengaged from the site is an effective strategy.

The most sustainable thing *you* can do is earn enough reputation to work the queues yourself, and edit without ending up in the queue. The more people, the faster the work gets done!

Comment: I totally agree with some of the points you've written, but that typo in the ***title*** of an ***HNQ***, being there for several hours, is extreme. Maybe there's not much in the queue, but the time-delay in addressing what's in the queue, is unacceptable if the title of an HNQ has that type of typo for so long!

Comment: @NikeDattani You use some pretty strong language there. Who, do you suppose, is responsible? Spoiler: _nobody_; this is a community. HNQs are picked by the system; we've never wanted that feature here, but we can't opt out. We've been asking for heads-up notifications about HNQs so we can polish them before they hit the network; we haven't gotten it. So there. Is it unfortunate if an HNQ is bad? Yes. Do we care? Not so much; typo or not, HNQ are _usually_ not what we'd like to showcase, anyway. So, if _you_ care, your best bet is to get on the queues yourself.

Comment: I respect you as a mod and someone with almost 70k rep, but you have a lot to learn about how HNQs work. Furthermore, the fact that no one is looking at the review queues fast enough to fix such a crucial typo in an HNQ with 1000 views, is not the responsibility of "nobody". I've never seen a typo like that survive so long on the HNQ list, in my whole decade of using SE (and I'm on here pretty much 24/7 in the last 2 years since I started the Matter Modeling SE).

Comment: `such a crucial typo` wait, what? Does it prevent to understand the title? Can it be misinterpreted? I fail to see why it is so `crucial` and `extreme`. Sure, it could have been easily corrected, but not doing so immediatly had absolutly no consequences…

Comment: I hope we can focus on making the site better together, and look for what we can do that will bring us together towards that goal.  Comment threads aren't really designed for extended discussion or debate and don't always work so well for that.  Also, if I might, I'd like to suggest that it might not be necessary to correct every  inaccuracy that we might see someone else making?  I hope we can keep this a welcoming and friendly place.  If you see something that violates our Code of Conduct or doesn't seem constructive, please feel free to flag at any point.