# How can effectively signal that a question should be closed?

Tags: support, flagging

The obvious answer is to flag them as *Needs improvement*. However this appears to be ineffective because all this does is push the items into the Close Votes queue and there [do not seem to be any active Close Votes reviewers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) (0 reviews today). Every single close flag I have raised is either on a question that would have been closed anyway, or aged away.

As such, I turned to flagging as *Very low quality* instead because these flags will not age away and will go to the moderators who can unilaterally close questions. But they all get declined as:

> Declined - This is what downvoting and comments are for.

How can I more effectively get an off-topic question closed? There are not enough Close Votes reviewers to actually make the close flags have any effect whatsoever. And the *Very low quality* flags get declined. And all the other flag options are not appropriate for off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, shoot.  Sorry about that.  That's embarassing.  We've had difficulties with lack of people handling the review queues for a while [1](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1742/755) [2](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1757/755), but I hadn't realized it had gotten so bad.  That sounds like a frustrating situation.  My apologies for it.

It appears no one has been reviewing the close votes queue in quite a while.  People do seem to have been reviewing the suggested edit queue, though there was still a backlog.  Unfortunately, this site has lost quite a few of its most active users over the past few years, which is a challenge.

Since you called attention to it, I just went through the entire close vote queue and suggested edit queue now and handled every one that I could.  I realize this is not a sustainable solution for the future.

In the future, I think the best I can suggest is to keep flagging as *Needs Improvement* with the specific close reason.  I realize this is not much of a solution, given your experience so far.  I'm hoping someone else will take up some of the load of the review queue, since I won't be able to reliably handle it.

My apologies again for the "can't-win" situation.

Comment: [Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163034/160998) is one that I close flagged and is still pending.

Comment: @user16217248, Yup, I saw that in the review and took no further action, because I don't feel confident about whether I'd be on solid ground unilaterally closing it.  I have to leave that to the community.